# Tips for making Generic Mobile Site

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, generics

I wanted to get some info/tips on making a Generic (iOS/Android/WebOS/etc...) Mobile Site.

Looking for:

- Speed (Loading)
- Cache (benefits?)
- DOCTYPE (I like HTML5)
- JavaScript Lib (I'm leaning towards [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) but it's still in Alpha)
- Etc...

Looking to avoid any pitfalls and take advantage of some frameworks as well.

The backend will be PHP/PostgreSQL driven and I do have a form submission (Thinking JSON but no experience with this), Security is also very important.

Looking forward to some great feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some personal preferences...

I'd assume most mobile browsers support html5.

Use sprites for your images, try to keep the # of http requests down.

jQM isn't too bad, there are others out there too.

Use json.

For security, use SSL if possible. If not possible, hash the passwords before transmitting.

With PHP make sure you clean any input from the browser.

Comment: jQM alternatives that would support most mobile OS's?

Comment: jQTouch is the only other one I use, designed for iOS based devices but works w/ android without problems.

Comment: hmm, Yeah I've seen jQTouch but didn't think it would work for me as I need it for 5+ different Mobile OS's (iOS, Android, WebOS, BB, Win7)